# Using a Tkinter button input to pass as argument

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm using tkinter to create an option menu, where choosing an option will call a function specific to each option. However, I'm unable to figure out exactly how to do that.

This is the code that is currently being used.

```
import pandas as pd
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#below code imports file needed at the moment
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename() #will open file from any location, does not need to be in the same place as the code script 
df = pd.read_csv(file_path) 
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Type'}, inplace=True) #renames the first unnamed column to type (drug available (DA) or not available (NA)
df.dropna(how = 'all', axis = 1, inplace = True) #drops the empty column present in each dataset, only drops it if the whole column is empty 

##plotting functions for both active and inactive pokes
def ActivePokes(df): 
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,7.5)
    df.plot()
    plt.xticks(range(0,len(df.Type)), df.Type)
    plt.ylabel("Number of Active Pokes")
    plt.xlabel("Sessions")
    plt.title("Number of Active Pokes vs Drug Availability")
    plt.show()
    
    
def InactivePokes(df): 
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,7.5)
    df.plot()
    plt.xticks(range(0,len(df.Type)), df.Type)
    plt.ylabel("Number of Inactive Pokes")
    plt.xlabel("Sessions")
    plt.title("Number of Inactive Pokes vs Drug Availability")
    plt.show()
    
def show(df): 
    if variable == options[1]:
        button[command] = ActivePokes(df)
    elif variable == options[2]: 
        button[command] = InactivePokes(df)
    else: 
        print("Error!")

options = [ "Choose Option",
           "1. Active pokes, Drug Available and No Drug Available sessions", 
           "2. Inactive pokes, Drug Available and No Drug Available sessions"]
button = Tk()
button.title("Dialog Window")

button.geometry('500x90')
variable = StringVar(button)
variable.set(options[0]) #default value, might change and edit as time passes 
option = OptionMenu(button, variable, *options, command = show)
option.pack()
button.mainloop()
```

I know the show() function is where the issue lies, but I'm not entirely sure how to rectify it.

Comment: You cannot do both `root = tk.Tk()` and `button = Tk()` at same time.. You only write one tk for entirely script.

Answer (score 1):

The other comments and answer address problems with creating two `Tk` objects and using `.get()` with a `StringVar`.

The `command = show` callback is passed the string value of the item chosen. In your `show( df )` when called from the Optionmenu will have `df` equal to one of the options.  It won't be a pandas dataframe.  Pure tkinter example below.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
    
root.geometry( '100x100' )

var = tk.StringVar( value = 'Option A' )

def on_choice( chosen ):
    """  The callback function for an Optionmenu choice.
            chosen: The text value of the item chosen. 
    """
    print( chosen, end = "  :  " )
    print( ' or from the StringVar: ', var.get() )

opt_list = [ 'Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C' ]

options = tk.OptionMenu( root, var, *opt_list, command = on_choice )

options.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem, you have created a tk instance called `root`, and then another one called `button`,why? perhaps you want button to be a tk.Button and not a tk instance? Not sure what is the intention here.

second, what is it `command` variable you want to change for button? (`button[command]`). if button where a tk.button, then perhaps you wanted to do `button['command'] = ...`, however, if the intention is to call the pokes functions why not calling them right away?

third problem is here:

```
def show(df):
    if variable == options[1]:
        button[command] = lambda: ActivePokes(df)
    elif variable == options[2]:
        button[command] = lambda: InactivePokes(df)
    else:
        print("Error!")
```

change `variable` for `variable.get()`