# 'str' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

Consistently getting above stated error when I try to call a function using the tkinter button.

So here is the example code used for this particular issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename() #will open file from any location, does not need to be in the same place as the code script 
df = pd.read_csv(file_path) 
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Type'}, inplace=True) #renames the first unnamed column to type (drug available (DA) or not available (NA)
df.dropna(how = 'all', axis = 1, inplace = True) #drops the empty column present in each dataset, only drops it if the whole column is empty 

##plotting functions for both active and inactive pokes
def ActivePokes(df): 
    df.plot(figsize = (12,7.5),
       xlabel = 'Number of active pokes', ylabel = 'Sessions', 
       title = 'Number of Active Pokes vs Drug Availability')
    plt.xticks(range(0,len(df.Type)), df.Type)
    
    
def InactivePokes(df): 
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,7.5)
    df.plot()
    plt.xticks(range(0,len(df.Type)), df.Type)
    plt.ylabel("Number of Inactive Pokes")
    plt.xlabel("Sessions")
    plt.title("Number of Inactive Pokes vs Drug Availability")
    plt.show()
    
    
def show(df): 
    if variable.get() == options[1]:
        ActivePokes(df)
    elif variable.get() == options[2]: 
        InactivePokes(df)
    else: 
        print("Error!")

options = [ "Choose Option",
           "1. Active pokes, Drug Available and No Drug Available sessions", 
           "2. Inactive pokes, Drug Available and No Drug Available sessions"]
button = Tk()
button.title("Dialog Window")

button.geometry('500x90')
variable = StringVar(button)
variable.set(options[0]) #default value, might change and edit as time passes 
option = OptionMenu(button, variable, *options, command = show)
option.pack()
button.mainloop()
```

However, the error I keep receiving is this:
[image: Error window saying 'str' has no attribute 'plot']

Is there any way this can be rectified and I can still produce the graphs needed while using the tkinter button?

Comment: Where are you calling `show()` function?

Comment: You need to amend your code in response to the answers and comments to yesterday's question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363202/using-a-tkinter-button-input-to-pass-as-argument'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Tkinter button input to pass as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363202/using-a-tkinter-button-input-to-pass-as-argument)

Comment: Also minor understanding questions to the solutions offered could have been clarified in the comments and does not necessarily need another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option Menu automatically passes the selected option to the command. Since you named the argument `df` in the function, the logical connection is `df = contentained_string_of_optionmenu` in the namespace of your function. However, since `df` origionally is a dataframe, you should just have to rename the argument/parameter of your function like:

```
def show(opt):
```

In addition it makes the `StringVar` useless since you can do:

```
    if opt == options[1]:
        ActivePokes(df)
    elif opt == options[2]: 
        InactivePokes(df)
    else: 
        print("Error!")
```

You might also choose to clear the argument `df` elsewhere since it's in the global namespace.